# How to setup and bring up can interface automatically on plug event?

Tags: usb, network-interface, events

I'm currently using a peak can interface to read can traffic. Every time I plug it to the computer, I must manually run:

```
sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000
sudo ip link set up can0
```

I could add those lines to my bashrc, but that would not work if I unplug and replug the device in the same session. Is there any plug event which I can associate a script to?

Comment: Thanks @eblock, didn't know about udev. That worked. If you like to, add an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[udev](https://www.tecmint.com/udev-for-device-detection-management-in-linux/) is usually the way to go for hotplug events.